# MongoDB: Ignore documents with array size null in aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have a variable roomsCount which is a filter for UI list of projects by amount of rooms. In the database, projects have value rooms which is an array, and store all data about them. This function sorts them, but here I also need to exclude projects where are no rooms or that field doesn't exist. I have found a way how to do it if there is not an aggregation, but how to avoid them in the pipeline?

```
  async aggregateAll(page, pageSize, filters, sortBy) {
    const options = {
      query: new FiltersQuery(filters),
      select: this.getAttributes(),
      sort: this.parseSortBy(sortBy),
      skip: (page - 1) * pageSize,
      limit: pageSize,
    };

    const query = this.projectModel.aggregate([
      { $match: options.query },
      {
        $addFields: { roomsCount: { $size: { $ifNull: ['$rooms', []] } } },
      },
      { $sort: { roomsCount: -1 } },
      { $skip: options.skip },
      { $limit: options.limit },
      { $project: options.select },
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should split the query.

First, check if field room exists with $exists.

```
$match: {room:{$exists:true}}
```

Then check the size, I think for check the size you will need to use $addFields, because with $size you can't use $gt.

```
$addFields: { roomSize: {$size:"$room"}},
$match: {roomSize:{$gt:0}}
```

Comment: May I add several $match in an aggregate query?

Comment: yes, you should remove your $addFields, and add my "solution"